# Spark SQL query with Int val is not working when we pass int val as argument

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql query  with integer value as one argument.

**Working:**

```
sqlContext.sql("select concat(MinRange, '-', MaxRange) from range where 20 >= MinRange and 20 < MaxRange")
```

**Not working:**

```
sqlContext.sql("select concat(MinRange, '-', MaxRange) from range where "+intval+">= MinRange and "+intval+" < MaxRange")
```

**Also this one with String interpolator, not working:**

```
sqlContext.sql(s"select concat(MinRange, '-', MaxRange) from range where $intval >= MinRange and $intval < MaxRange")
```

I'm sure , i am missing something very basic.

Comment: What is response for not working queries ?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @FaigB: Its not returning the output, first one returns the range.

Comment: I tried from another machine, all the approaches are working fine, i am not sure what is the issue..

Answer (score 1):

First construct the query string then execute it will work.

```
val intval=10

val qry= "select concat(MinRange, '-', MaxRange) from range where "+intval+">= MinRange and "+intval+" < MaxRange"

sqlContext.sql(qry)
```

Comment: Why is that? what is the problem when we directly use inside sql method?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check below:

**1)**
Since u r building the <Column Name> run-time, can you check if the <Column Name> actually exists in "range" table.

**2)**
Did you check what is the actual value of *intVal* variable during run-time? Make sure it is not getting null value, by giving a default value.